# intellij IDEA plugin: Problems understanding LineMarkerProvider and ReferenceContributor

Tags: xml, plugins, navigation, intellij-idea

I am working on a IDEA plugin that should provide navigation between different XML files and between XML and Java sources. It's a bit similar to the Spring support.

The to-be-supported XML tags have a <name> child (in contrast to the id attribute in Spring) and references are just like spring: ref="..." Navigation to Java sources will be a later step. There is also a naming convention for the xml files to support for the new plugin: *-definitions.xml

At the moment, I am stuck at one of the first steps: LineMarkerProvider and ReferenceContributor.

I used the "Custom Language Support" example as starting point. But because I do not have a custom language but want to extend xml functionality instead, I removed the lexer, parser, file factory etc ... and included only a LineMarkerProvider and a ReferenceContributor.

So what I have up to now is:

- class DefinitionsReference extends PsiReferenceBase
- class DefinitionsUtil (similar to SimplePsiImplUtil)
- class DefinitionsLineMarkerProvider extends RelatedItemLineMarkerProvider
- class DefinitionsReferenceContributor extends PsiReferenceContributor

I registered the LineMarkerProvider (language=XML) and ReferenceContributor in plugin.xml and I added some logging output to verify if they are called and if the results are empty or not.

Although ReferenceContributor.PsiReferenceProvider.getReferencesByElement() as well as DefinitionsReference.multiResolve() and reslove() indeed return some non-empty results and LineMarkerProvider.collectNavigationMarkers() does find some places to mark, I do neither get navigation gutter icons nor can I navigate from a ref= to the corresponding  tag. It says "cannot find declaration to go to".

Seems I missed some important detail.

What should I look for first ?

Or is it the completely wrong approach ?

**Edit:**

This is one of the XML files to be supported:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<event-definitions>
  <data-source-definition>
    <name>event.eventDataSource</name>
    <class>...</class>
  </data-source-definition>

  <plugin-definition>
    <name>event.taskPlugin</name>
    <class>...</class>
    <title>...</title>

    <data-source ref="event.eventDataSource">
      <property>eventDataSource</property>
    </data-source>
    <data-source ref="personDataSource"/> <!-- defined in other XML file -->
    ... more data-sources ...
  </plugin-definition>

  <editor-definition>
    <name>event.admin.Editor</name>
    <editor>...</editor>
    <title>...</title>
    <editor-view>...</editor-view>

    <data-source ref="event.eventDataSource"/>
    <data-source ref="personDataSource"/> <!-- defined in other XML file -->
    ... more data-sources ...

    <plugin ref="event.taskPlugin">
      ...
    </plugin>
    <plugin ref="assignment.ratingPlugin"> <!-- defined in other XML file -->
      ...
    </plugin>
    ... more plugins ...
  </editor-definition>
</event-definitions>
```

This is my ReferenceContributor:

```
public class DefinitionsReferenceContributor extends PsiReferenceContributor {
    @Override
    public void registerReferenceProviders(PsiReferenceRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.registerReferenceProvider(PlatformPatterns.psiElement(XmlTag.class),
                new PsiReferenceProvider() {
                    @NotNull
                    @Override
                    public PsiReference[] getReferencesByElement(@NotNull PsiElement element, @NotNull ProcessingContext context) {
                        XmlTag tag = (XmlTag) element;
                        final String localName = tag.getLocalName();
                        if ("name".equals(localName)) {
                            final PsiReference[] psiReferences = DefinitionsUtil.matchTag((XmlTag) element);
                            return psiReferences;
                        } else {
                            return new PsiReference[0];
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

My LineMarkerProvider:

```
public class DefinitionsLineMarkerProvider extends RelatedItemLineMarkerProvider {

    @Override
    protected void collectNavigationMarkers(@NotNull PsiElement element, Collection<? super RelatedItemLineMarkerInfo> result) {
        if (element instanceof XmlTag) {
            XmlTag tag = (XmlTag) element;
            final String localName = tag.getLocalName();
            if ("name".equals(localName)) {
                final Project project = element.getProject();
                final String tagName = DefinitionsUtil.getTagName(tag);
                if (tagName != null) {
                    final List<XmlTag> matchingTags = DefinitionsUtil.findMatchingReferences(project, tagName);
                    if (matchingTags.size() > 0) {
                      NavigationGutterIconBuilder<PsiElement> builder =
                              NavigationGutterIconBuilder.create(SmotiveDefinitionsIcons.FILE).
                                      setTargets(matchingTags).
                                      setTooltipText("Navigate to a sMOTIVE Definition");
                      result.add(builder.createLineMarkerInfo(element));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                final String ref = DefinitionsUtil.getRefValue(tag);
                if (ref != null) {
                    final Project project = element.getProject();
                    final List<XmlTag> matchingTags = DefinitionsUtil.findMatchingTags(project, ref);
                    if (matchingTags.size() > 0) {
                        NavigationGutterIconBuilder<PsiElement> builder =
                              NavigationGutterIconBuilder.create(SmotiveDefinitionsIcons.FILE).
                                    setTargets(matchingTags).
                                    setTooltipText("Navigate to a sMOTIVE Definition");
                        result.add(builder.createLineMarkerInfo(element));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, the extensions section of my plugin.xml:

```
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <codeInsight.lineMarkerProvider language="XML" implementationClass="de.smotive.tools.navigation.definitions.DefinitionsLineMarkerProvider"/>
    <psi.referenceContributor implementation="de.smotive.tools.navigation.definitions.DefinitionsReferenceContributor"/>
</extensions>
```

I omitted the DefinitionsUtil because of it's size. If it turns out to be required for finding the solution, I will add it later on.

Comment: Which method in LineMarkerProvider do you implement?
How do you register your reference contributor, a code sample maybe?

In general, I'd suggest you to just put a breakpoint in your code and step to see what happens to the objects you return. With references it should be quite easy, with line markers a bit harder but you can still spot some code that filters them out.

Comment: @Peter: I have added some code samples to my question.

Comment: Thanks! Have you put breakpoints to this code and checked that it's called and what happens to its return values next?